# Como asigno una formula matemática a una variable?

Tags: javascript

Quería saber si había alguna manera de asignar una función matemática compleja a una variable para ser reutilizada varias veces y así simplificar su uso.

La fórmula en cuestión es la siguiente:

```
CostGen[i] * ((Math.pow(CoefGen[i], LvlGen[i]) * (Math.pow(CoefGen[i], rAmount) - 1)) / (CoefGen[i] - 1))
```

Como pueden ver, el hecho de que utilice arrays complica la situación, ya que si fuera algo simple como `(x/4)*7`, esto sería mas fácil.

Dicho eso, puedo asignar la fórmula expresada arriba a alguna variable o función, para no tener que copiar y pegarla cada vez que necesita ser usada?

Gracias.-

Comment: Puedes crear una funcion y pasarle los parametros que necesites.

Comment: @alanfcm como se haría eso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente crea una funcion con la formula que necesitas y pasale los parametros necesarios.  Algo asi:

```js
function formula(CostGen, CoefGen, LvlGen, rAmount) {
  return CostGen * ((Math.pow(CoefGen, LvlGen) * (Math.pow(CoefGen, rAmount) - 1)) / (CoefGen - 1));
}

console.log(formula(1,2,3,4));
```

Comment: muchas gracias! te hago otra pregunta: como aplicaría luego tal función dentro de un loop for? escribiría:

function formula(CostGen[i], CoefGen[i], LvlGen[i], rAmount)
es esto correcto?

Comment: Correcto @p14082003

Comment: muchas gracias! @alanfcm

Answer (score 0):

en javascript, existe un funcion "eval", que realiza el calculo de alguna funcion definida en una variable string:

```
fx="x*2+3";
x=4;
resultado=eval(fx)
```

el valor de resultado es 11, espero te sirva

Comment: es una función peligrosa, que ejecuta el código el cual es pasado con los privilegios de quien llama. 
 Si ejecuta eval() con una cadena de caracteres que podría ser afectada por un elemento malicioso, 
 podría terminar ejecutando código malicioso dentro de la computadora del usuario con los permisos 
 de su página o extensión web

Comment: estamos completamente de acuerdo, solo debe ser usado en un ambiente controlado, pero es la forma más sencilla y rápida para evaluar una función o formula matemática